# How do I display old and actual price of Product correctly in nopCommerce?

Tags: css, themes, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-themes

I'm using MyStore Theme for my webshop. I have a product with old price and actual price. But it's not showing correctly in the web browser.

As highlighted in the picture bellow (second product soccer ball).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks CSS issue, I think issue is in position. If possible please send site URL so one can check on that and inspect it.

P.S

I have tried to apply some CSS, See I am not CSS developer but I have tried something. Hope it helps.

```
<div class="prices">
<span class="price old-price" style="
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
">€35,00</span>
<span class="price actual-price" style="
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
">€30,00</span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Krutal Modi, I applied the following changes:

**--Solution--**

**.product-grid .product-item .prices .actual-price**

- Deleted vertical-align: middle;
- Added position: relative;
- Added top: 10px;

**.item-box .old-price**

- Added position: relative;
- Added top: 10px;

**--Result--**

[image]